# Can registry keys be deleted only in one level up?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, registrykey

In our application we are having different components and registry key will be created in component Name.

For ex.

We are having a component named Notification and we are having registry key as follows

```
RegistryKey rKeyNotification = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\CompanyName\\ProdName\\Notification");
```

Now i wanted to delete this key and all the subkeys.

I was trying to delete this rKeyNotification completely. But i don't find any way.

I was trying like follows.

```
if (rKeyNotification != null) {

   rKeyNotification.DeleteSubKeyTree("Notification");
}
```

But this piece will look for  `RegistryKey rKeyNotification =Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\CompanyName\\ProdName\\Notification\\Notification");`

There is no option like `rKeyNotification.DeleteSubKeyTree()`

Should i always go up one level `(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\CompanyName\\ProdName)` then only delete the key?

Comment: Could you post the relevant bit of the code you are using to delete the key?

Comment: It kind of makes sense - what would the state of `rkeyNotification` be like after it allowed the delete? There's no other way to obtain a `RegistryKey` object that doesn't actually refer to a real key in the registry, but there's no way to prevent you calling further methods on it after the delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to delete a key itself, but you can use `Registry.LocalMachine` directly:

```
string keyname = @"SOFTWARE\CompanyName\ProdName\Notification";
Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyname);
```